# GridView, It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

THIS is my api code with entity framework
public class UpdateHotelInfoesController : ApiController
    {
        private UpdateHotelInfoEntities db = new UpdateHotelInfoEntities();

```
    // GET: api/UpdateHotelInfoes
    public IQueryable<UpdateHotelInfo> GetUpdateHotelInfo()
    {
        return db.UpdateHotelInfo;
    }

    // GET: api/UpdateHotelInfoes/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(UpdateHotelInfo))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUpdateHotelInfo(int id)
    {
        UpdateHotelInfo updateHotelInfo = db.UpdateHotelInfo.Find(id);
        if (updateHotelInfo == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(updateHotelInfo);
    }
```

c# code

```
protected async void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        up.POSTAL_CODE = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Base_URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        StringContent con = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(up), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/UpdateHotelInfoes/" + TextBox2.Text);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {            
              var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainObject>(data);

                     GridView1.DataSource = a;
                     GridView1.DataBind();
                 }
```

source code of gridview control

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HOTEL_NAME" HeaderText="HOTEL_NAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ADDRESS_LINE" HeaderText="ADDRESS_LINE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AREA" HeaderText="AREA" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CITY" HeaderText="CITY" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="POSTAL_CODE" HeaderText="POSTAL_CODE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="STATE" HeaderText="STATE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="COUNTRY" HeaderText="COUNTRY" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PHONE_NUMBER" HeaderText="PHONE_NUMBER" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LANDLINE" HeaderText="LANDLINE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EMAIL_ID" HeaderText="EMAIL_ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="WEBSITE" HeaderText="WEBSITE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PROPERTY_TYPE" HeaderText="PROPERTY_TYPE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PROPERTY_GRADE" HeaderText="PROPERTY_GRADE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="REGISTRATION" HeaderText="REGISTRATION" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

why the data is not displaying in gridview ,and getting the error
gridview1.datasource=a;>>>>GridView, It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource

what are the changes i have to do to get rid of this issue.anyone know how to get rid of this .

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT, click the edit button and edit the question into better form and also format the code properly. Then explain what is wrong and what you need help with.

Comment: GridView.DataSource expects a collection and not a single object

Comment: Use a.List() data source should be collection not a object.

Comment: @virender why is UpdateHotelInfo needed to answer the question? It does not matter what it is ... it is obviously not a collection

Comment: See If UpdateHotelInfo is object and contains any collection then use that collection like a.CustomerData.